# Incorrect Protocol Buffer Deserialization/Marshaling In Spring AMQP

Tags: java, go, deserialization, protocol-buffers, spring-amqp

I am trying to figure out why my protocol buffer payload is being incorrectly de-serialized when received from a Spring AMQP listener in my Java app.
The protocol buffer is written in a Go service and sent to a Rabbit MQ instance which is then picked up by the Java Spring app and de-serialized into an object instance.

For some reason when received the marshalled object has field `2` with the value of field `1` while field `1` is `null` in the resulting object.
Additionally the repeated `network_interfaces` field with key `5` is `null` on the object.

Interestingly if I use the debugger when picking up a message from the queue, the missing fields are visible and contain the correct data on the instantiated protobuf object under `unknownFields` so it looks like a case of the proto parser not working correctly.
**The debugger shows that the field keys are off, i.e. field `1` has the key `2` and so on.**

So far I have:

- Verified the proto files are the same in both services, the Spring app is using the proto file from the other repo by importing it as a git submodule
- Attempted to use a `Spring.messaging.amqp` MessageConverter to deserialize the proto explicitly based on message headers with no success
- Tried different message content type and encoding headers when sending the message, these don't appear to make a difference as I am only using the message body.
- Verified that if the Go app listens to the queue that it can deserialize and unmarshal a message it sent correctly, so this has to be a Spring config issue or similar.

**The Proto3 message definition in question:**

```
message HostStateMessage {

  message NetworkInterface {
    string name = 1;
    string mac_address = 2;
    string ipv4 = 3;
    string ipv6 = 4;
  }

  string hostname = 1;
  string description = 2;
  HostType host_type = 3;
  repeated NetworkInterface network_interfaces = 4;
}
```

The Go function which writes the protocol buffer to RabbitMQ as a message:

```
func PublishHostMessage(config *AMQPQueueConfiguration, conn *amqp.Connection, message *protos.HostStateMessage) error {
    channel, err := conn.Channel()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Creating channel failed: %s\n", err)
        return err
    }

    queue, err := channel.QueueDeclare(config.HostQueueName, true, false, false, false, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Failed to declare queue: %s\n", err)
        return err
    }

    serialMsg, err := proto.Marshal(message)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Failed to serialize proto message: %s\n", err)
        return err
    }
    headers := amqp.Table{}
    headers["messageType"] = "HostStateMessage"
    fmt.Println(string(serialMsg))
    err = channel.Publish("", queue.Name, false, false, amqp.Publishing{Headers: headers, ContentType: "application/x-protobuf", Body: serialMsg})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Failed to send message: %s\n", err)
        return err
    }

    fmt.Printf("Sent host message at: %s\n", time.Now())
    return nil
}
```

The MessageReceiver.java Class:

```
@Service
public class MessageReceiver {

  @Autowired RabbitConfiguration rabbitConfiguration;
  @Autowired HostDao hostDao;

  @RabbitListener(queues = "#{rabbitConfiguration.hostQueueName}")
  public void consumeHostNotification(Message in) {
    try {
      HostStateMessage message = HostStateMessage.parseFrom(in.getBody());
      hostDao.addOrUpdateHostStateFromMessage(message);
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
  }
}
```

The Spring AMQP @Configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

  @Value("${rabbitmq.hostname}")
  private String queueHost;

  @Value("${rabbitmq.port}")
  private int queuePort;

  @Value("${rabbitmq.queues.host-queue-name}")
  public String hostQueueName;

  @Bean
  public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new CachingConnectionFactory(queueHost, queuePort);
  }

  @Bean
  public Queue hostNotificationQueue() {
    return new Queue(hostQueueName);
  }
}
```

Go is using `google.golang.org/protobuf v1.27.1` in Go modules.

Java is using `com.google.protobuf 3.19.4` as a Maven dependency. Along with `protobuf-maven-plugin 0.6.1` to do the compilation with protoc.

This is a really confusing issue, would be great to get some insight.

Comment: *Verified the proto files are the same in both services* — just to be clear, the `.proto` files aren't really relevant, what is relevant is the classes and types generated from those files in the target language. So did you verify that the classes imported by the Java code are those generated from the latest version of the `.proto` files?

Comment: Thanks @blackgreen - I had verified the Java generated protobuf multiple times but had not thought to do the same for the Go generated code. Turns out that was out of date. Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

After checking the that the Java generated protobuf class was correct multiple I times, I realised that I had not verified the Go generated protobuf.

Turns out the script I was using to call protoc-gen-go had failed silently and the Go service was using an outdated version of the message with an additional field with the key `1`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).